# How do I build HTML from a jquery matched set?

Tags: jquery, each

I have this JSFiddle as a test, http://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/7ctjcv4y/2/

Essentially I have this HTML:

```
<div class="doc-section" data-title="One"></div>
<div class="doc-section" data-title="Two"></div>
<div class="doc-section" data-title="Three"></div>
<div class="doc-section" data-title="Four"></div>
<div class="doc-section" data-title="Five"></div>
<div class="doc-section" data-title="Six"></div>

<ol id="table-of-contents"></ol>
```

And this jquery:

```
var $toc = $("#table-of-contents");

$("div.doc-section").each(function(index, item){
   var title = $(item).attr("data-title");
    var li = $("li").text(title);
    $toc.append(li);
});
```

What I want is this:

```
<ol id="table-of-contents">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ol>
```

This should work, but in JSFiddle I'm not getting anything, and in my actual production code, I'm getting 70 li elements, and they all say "Six".

I'm stumped.  Any help is appreciated.  How can I get this resulting HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **create** element, with this syntax: `$("<li></li>")`.

```
var $toc = $("#table-of-contents");

$("div.doc-section").each(function(index, item){
   var title = $(item).attr("data-title");
   var li = $("<li></li>").text(title);
   $toc.append(li);
});
```

You wrote:

```
var li = $("li").text(title);
```

Actually you are changing the text of all `li` elements in your page with `title` variable (you are selecting elements instead of creating).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ctjcv4y/4/).

Comment: Good thing it only took me four hours to figure out.  :^)

Answer (score 1):

you missed opening and closing angular brackets while creating li. see the updated [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/7ctjcv4y/5/)

```
var $toc = $("#table-of-contents");
$toc.empty();
$("div.doc-section").each(function(index, item){
    //console.log(item);
   var title = $(item).attr("data-title");
    var li = $("<li>").text(title);
    $toc.append(li);
});
```

also do not forget to call `$toc.empty()` if you are calling this function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This is u need

```
var $toc = $("#table-of-contents");

$("div.doc-section").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
    var li = "<li>"+title+"</li>";
    $toc.append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("div.doc-section").map(function(index, item){
  $toc.append('<li>'+$(item).data('title')+'</li>');//or $toc.append($('<li>').html($(item).data('title')));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0rv91zaL/)**

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  Stupid.  I needed to change this:

```
var li = $("li").text(title);
```

... to this...

```
var li = $("<li>").text(title);
```

BTW, I really didn't expect this many correct answers this quickly.  Thanks to everyone.